# Why is $(A^\top A \mathbf{x}, \mathbf{x}) = (A \mathbf{x}, A \mathbf{x})$?

Tags: inner-products

Let $(\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{y})$ denote the inner product between $\mathbf{x}$ and $\mathbf{y}$, and let $A$ be a real matrix.  Why is $(A^\top A \mathbf{x}, \mathbf{x}) = (A \mathbf{x}, A \mathbf{x})$?

Using the scalar product it's easy to see that
$$
\begin{align}
(A^\top A \mathbf{x})^\top \mathbf{x} &= \mathbf{x}^\top A^\top A \mathbf{x} \\
&= (A \mathbf{x})^\top A \mathbf{x} 
\end{align}
$$
but using only the properties of the inner product I fail to see how one gets the result.

#Edit:
To be clear, I'm asking how one comes to the conclusion that $(A^\top A \mathbf{x}, \mathbf{x}) = (A \mathbf{x}, A \mathbf{x})$, independently of how the inner product is defined (ie. only using the axioms of the inner product), so if your answer relies on a particular definition of the inner product such as $(\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{y}) := \mathbf{x}^\top\mathbf{y}$, it's not good.

#Edit 2:
The equality I'm asking about can be found in the book [Linear Algebra Done Wrong](https://sites.google.com/a/brown.edu/sergei-treil-homepage/linear-algebra-done-wrong) (pdf) by Sergei Treil (p. 172), although here I'm interested only in the case of real matrices in the book it covers the complex case as well.

Comment: You might want to sharpen your question a bit, as you’re starting to get a rash of answers that just repeat what you’ve written.

Comment: Note that this equation doesn’t hold for inner product spaces over the complex numbers.

Comment: It is a way of defining the transpose of an operator, and the inner product is intrinsic to this definition.

Comment: What is your background?  Have you taken a course which explains the theory behind linear algebra or just a sophomore level (at least at my university)  computational linear algebra course?

Comment: To build on @hardmath’s comment, one approach is to prove that given a matrix $A$, there is a unique $B$ such that $(A\mathbf u,\mathbf v)=(\mathbf u,B\mathbf v)$, which you can do using bilinearity, and then show that $B=A^T$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to understand it without regards to a specific inner product, you must understand what the transpose is without regards to a specific matrix representation.  More specifically, you need to understand what the [*adjoint*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermitian_adjoint) of a linear operator is.

> Given a linear operator $T:V\to V$ on an inner product space $V$ with inner product $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$,  the *adjoint* of $T$ is the operator $T^*:V\to V$ such that 
>   $$ \langle Tx,y\rangle=\langle x,T^*y\rangle $$
>   for all $x,y\in V$.

The definition of the adjoint is a generalization of the transpose for real inner product spaces, and of the conjugate transpose for complex inner product spaces.  One of the first results after obtaining this result is the following

> The adjoint of an adjoint operator is the original operator.  That is,
>   $$ (T^*)^*=T $$

Using this we can see that, using the terminology in the first block, for $x,y\in V$ we have
$$ \langle T^*Tx,y\rangle=\langle Tx,(T^*)^*y\rangle=\langle Tx,Ty\rangle. $$

Answer (score 3):

Well, I don't think what you're asking can be proven, because I don't think it's true for all inner products on $\mathbf{R}^n$. Therefore, you have to specifically use the defined inner product.

We have that $\langle x,y\rangle$ is an inner product on $\mathbf R^n$ if and only if
$$\langle x,y\rangle = x^\intercal My$$
for a symmetric, positive definite matrix $M$, [see here](https://math.berkeley.edu/~peyam/Math110Sp13/Handouts/Dot%20products.pdf). Hence, we have that
$$\langle A^\intercal A x,x\rangle = (A^\intercal A x)^\intercal M x = x^\intercal A^\intercal A Mx = (Ax)^\intercal A Mx $$
whereas
$$\langle Ax, Ax\rangle = (Ax)^\intercal M Ax.$$

So they are only equal in general if $M$ and $A$ commute, which happens e.g. when $M = I_n$ is the idendity matrix which gives the standard inner product on $\mathbf R^n$.

Comment: Thanks, it was helpful. I could have accepted your answer but in the end I decided to go with Aweygan's.

Answer (score 1):

We can generalize your question a little by looking at $$\langle A^\top x,y \rangle = \langle x,Ay \rangle.$$

It does not make sense to ask your question about a "general inner product," since you are working with vectors and matrices, and <s>thus</s> your inner product is a very particular one, namely $\langle x,y \rangle = x^\top y$ for real vectors. [But there are other inner products for $\mathbb{R}^n$.]

As amd pointed out, if you are working with complex vectors, then <s>the</s> an inner product (one of many) is $\langle x,y\rangle = x^* y$ where $x^*$ denotes the *conjugate* transpose. Then a similar argument shows $\langle A^* x, y\rangle = \langle x,Ay \rangle$. So the mystery operator that goes in the place of $A^\top$ in your question does very much depend on what your inner product actually is.

However, if you do want to talk about more general cases, then this concept is known as an [adjoint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermitian_adjoint) of an operator. More generally (the following is informal) if you have an arbitrary inner product space $H$ and a linear operator $A:H\to H$, then the adjoint of $A$ is **defined** to be the linear operator $A^*$ that satisfies $\langle A^* x,y\rangle = \langle x,A y\rangle$ for all $x,y \in H$. In your example, $H$ is $\mathbb{R}^n$ with the usual dot product, linear operators are matrices in $\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$, and the adjoint ends up being the matrix transpose. Similarly for $H=\mathbb{C}^n$, linear operators are matrices in $\mathbb{C}^{n \times n}$ and the adjoint ends up being the matrix conjugate transpose.

Comment: Is this not an inner product on $\mathbf R^2$:
$\langle x, y\rangle = 2x_1 y_1 + 3 x_2 y_2 \neq x^\intercal y? $

Answer (score 0):

We have $$(A^TAx,x)=[A^TAx]^Tx=[A^T(Ax)]^Tx=[(Ax)^TA]x=(Ax)^T(Ax)=(Ax,Ax)$$

Comment: The OP already said that.

Comment: I don't get what he is asking then... This just uses the definition of the inner/scalar product, and basic facts about the transpose.

Comment: @smcc I agree and posted a similar solution.

Comment: @amd The OP didn't follow through with the last step, which might just be the "missing link."

Comment: @Dr.MV The OP writes “... but using only the properties of the inner product,” which suggests to me that he wants a different proof.

Comment: @amd I read that, but the only "property" that we need is the definition of the inner product. ;-))

Answer (score -1):

In your work, we have $(Ax)^T Ax$. The inner product is $(x, y) = x^T y$. Now set $x=Ax, y=Ax$, and it becomes clear. You transpose the first argument and multiply by the second.